# How to increase the time tooltips remain visible in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tooltip

By default, Visual Studio tooltips remain visible for 10 seconds and then they disappear. I find this time too short to read some of the longer tooltips. Is there a way to increase the time they remain visible?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I encounter such a problem, I just press print screen and read the text in my [favorite paint program](http://paint.net/).

I never understood why the tooltip timeout is not based on the length of the content.

Comment: Yeah, after swearing a few words at whoever chose a useful and often quite detailed tooltip to disappear on its own accord...

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that ToolTips preferences are controlled at the system display level (i.e., as part of Windows settings). As far as I know, there is still no way to lengthen the time that a tip is displayed.

I recommend [Shay Erlichmen's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700245/366904) of using print screen to capture the tip. Paste into a paint program and you can read the whole thing. Then close the paint program without saving.