# Intellisense QuickInfo disappears after 10 seconds

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know if there is a way to keep the Intellisense QuickInfo from disappearing after 10 seconds? After I type a period to get the member list, I usually like to read the QuickInfo for the highlighted member. However, it automatically disappears after 10 seconds and I usually can't finish reading the content in that short time.

BTW, when I refer to "QuickInfo," I'm referring to the box that shows up to the right of the member list which contains the complete member signature and a description. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no proper solution to your problem, because the tooltips are controlled by the system not the visual studio process. But you can print the screen to capture the tooltip and then paste it to paint like in this answer.

[How to increase the time tooltips remain visible in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699622/how-to-increase-the-time-tooltips-remain-visible-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think I'll stick with my current approach, which is to arrow-up/arrow-down to get the tooltip to reappear.